# Operator chaining in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Is it possible to use column merge during operator chaining in pandas ? For example,

```
df2 = df[(df['A'] < 4) & (df['B'] >= 4) & (df['C'] >= 4)]
```

Here, both B & C have same condition. i.e both the columns should have a value > 4. When I re-write it as,

```
df2 = df[(df['A'] < 4) & (df['B','C'] >= 4)]
```

I get an error. Is there an efficient way to write this operator chaining ?

Thanks in Advance.

AP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could select multiple columns by [indexing with a *list*](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#basics) of column names, and then [using `all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) to combine the results:

```
df2 = df[(df['A'] < 4) & (df[['B','C']] >= 4).all(axis='columns')]
```

Note the double brackets in `df[['B','C']]`. This returns a sub-DataFrame of `df` with columns `B` and `C`. 
Although together it might look like some kind of special double bracket syntax, it isn't really special -- evaluation follows normal Python rules -- it is just that the meaning of the inner and outer brackets are different. The outer brackets indicate we are indexing `df`. The inner brackets are used to form the list `['B','C']`. Together they induce Python to call [`df.__getitem__(['B','C'])`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__).

---

**Why does `df['B','C']` raise a KeyError**:

`df['B','C']` is equivalent to `df[('B','C')]`.  `df[('B','C')]` has a very
different meaning than `df[['B','C']]`.  When indexing a DataFrame, Pandas
interprets the tuple `('B','C')` as a single column label. This is particularly
useful for DataFrames with [MultiIndexed columns](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html). In that case it selects the column whose first MultiIndexed column level equals `B` and whose second column level equals `C`.  Since your DataFrame doesn't have a MultiIndexed column index nor a single column with the (peculiar) name `('B','C')`, a KeyError is raised when you evaluate `df['B','C']`.

---

**An example of a single-indexed DataFrame where `df['B','C']` doesn't raise a KeyError**:

```
In [15]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,3)), columns=[('A','B'),('B','C'),('B','D')])

In [16]: df
Out[16]: 
   (A, B)  (B, C)  (B, D)
0       5       2       1
1       5       5       3
2       8       8       1
3       9       2       9
4       3       5       8

In [17]: df['B','C']
Out[17]: 
0    2
1    5
2    8
3    2
4    5
Name: (B, C), dtype: int64
```

---

**An example of a MultiIndexed DataFrame where `df['B','C']` doesn't raise a KeyError**:

```
In [20]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,3)), columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('A','B'),('B','C'),('C','D')]))

In [21]: df
Out[21]: 
   A  B  C
   B  C  D
0  6  1  1
1  5  1  0
2  5  7  8
3  6  9  9
4  5  5  0

In [22]: df['B','C']
Out[22]: 
0    1
1    1
2    7
3    9
4    5
Name: (B, C), dtype: int64
```